# What is the best way to create a single app that hosts multiple user types in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am creating a app in which 4 distinct user types will share much of the same codebase. I want to be able to navigate to a particular version of the app based on information that is received about the user upon sign-in. Each app version has multiple pages, distinct color schemes, different permissions, etc, but they all share the same general flow and have a very similar layout. What is the most efficient way to go about  this? The only solutions I can think of are:

1. Using some type of logic to conditionally render different home screens based on the users type. It's my most promising solution, but I don't really like the idea of this because I'd essentially be copying and pasting the shared code for each version of the app and would be left with a lot to keep track of and maintain.
2. Passing the user type through constructors and using that to alter each page... ewww
3. Some type of state management system that is probably possible but I haven't figured out yet.

I've looked into Flutter's support of flavors, but it seems that is only useful for being able to split apps up on runtime. Any insights on this?

Comment: Are you talking about Android user profiles, or something like Firebase auth ?

Comment: Firebase auth - but I'll be determining the login type based on a field from my users collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State management is the way to go. Learn to use provider, flutter_bloc or any other solution. Recover the user type in there, and you will be able to access it throughout the different pages.

You could do something like creating a class with all the specific parameters (colors, permissions, etc), and create an object for each user type :

```
class Params {
  Params(this.color, this.permission);
  Color color;
  int permission;
}

Map<String, Params> params = {
  "admin": Params(Colors.red, 5),
  "guest": Params(Colors.grey, 0)
};

// Somewhere in the widget tree
color: params[userType].color,
```

Not the cleanest solution, but it works.

And yes, try to duplicate code as little as possible. You can use conditions, for loops and other syntactic sugar inside the widget tree to make it adapt to the user state.

Comment: do you know if there is a way to dynamically set the primary swatch/color based on the type of user that signs in? I decided to go down the provider path, and can't seem to get that to work

Comment: Yes. Look at the provider example tab. The `Provider` is at the very top of the tree, in the `runApp()` call. This means you can access its state from the `ThemeData`, and therefore set its `primaryColor` parameter according to it. This is how dynamic theming like dark mode is achieved.